# How to display a bmp image in android

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

I'm new to java and android development. I tried to find answer to this question but it seems that the is obvious so nobody asks that..
I used this example to display an image:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String str="http://logproj.500mb.net/image.php?id=8";
    ImageView imView;
    imView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
     try{
    url = new URL(str);
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
            HttpURLConnection conn =  (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            conn.connect();
            int length = conn.getContentLength();

            int[] bitmapData =new int[length];
            byte[] bitmapData2 =new byte[length];

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            imView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

It works great for jpg images, but my image is bmp and application crashes or "stopps unexpectadly".

I hope you'll help with this problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically change images in your program or do you want your images fixed? If the image is fixed you don't need to program it in, you just have to drop it in the drawable-hdpi folder under res and then set that image to the imgveiw in the layout xml file.

Comment: So I tried everything you suggested but nothing worked, but finally I've found solution: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/. This really worked for me. 
I was pleasantly surprised when there apeeared so many good answers for my question. Before I was asking on other sites (russian Google Baraza, for example), but these were not specialised on programming. Great thanks for everybody!

Answer (score 2):

try this using apaches web client. This should work. Let me know.

```
public static Bitmap decodeFromUrl(HttpClient client, URL url, Config bitmapCOnfig)
{
    HttpResponse response=null;
    Bitmap b=null;
    InputStream instream=null;

    BitmapFactory.Options decodeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    decodeOptions.inPreferredConfig = bitmapCOnfig;
    try
    {
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
        response = client.execute(request);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200)
        {
            Log.d("Bad response on " + url.toString());
            Log.d("http response: " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
            return null;
        }
        BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity());
        instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream, null, decodeOptions);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d("error decoding bitmap from:" + url, ex);
        if (response != null)
        {
            Log.d("http status: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (instream != null)
        {
            try {
                instream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("error closing stream", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

dont forget to make a call to this function from inside an async task.

Comment: I'm totally sorry - I didn't see you'd put the last line in your post! That's my bad for posting as a answer and not a comment :(

Answer (score 2):

First of all - you shouldn't be running a http connection on the main UI thread. On newer versions of android this will throw a networkOnUIThreadException causing a force close.

I'd suggest writing an `AsyncTask` to run your download on a background thread. The decodeFromUrl written by WIIJBD looks like it should work just fine so if you called that function you could get it to return you the bitmap to the UI thread onPostExecute() and set in in the ImageView there

Async Task Tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Any more questions let me know

Comment: +1 up for this. Yeah Async tasks are great, I love them and use them as much as possible where ever relevant. Too many people don't use Async tasks where they should, and this is part of what causes the false assumption that "iphones are more 'smooth' than android", simply because of poor programming. Truth is either one can be smooth or choppy, but android doesn't have such hard set standards and quality control as does apple.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use .bmp files. Use .png files instead. Or .gif -- which is less preferable on android, but does work.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on some android apps with images, and if the image is large the app crashed a lot, so I googled and found this one on android developer network, pretty good.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

What I will recommend to you is that, you could download and save the image to external storage - like SD card, and then load it and display this time you can reduce its quality based on your memory usage.

Also download a image is time-consuming part in your app, so better put these codes to another thread or `AsyncTask` (more better, IMO), so it won't stop UI main thread while downloading it from internet, after it completed you can display it as well.

Hope it helps.